# adding column to the traces table - Enterprise logging database

Tags: wcf, logging, enterprise-library, semantic-logging

I'm using the **Enterprise semantic logging** on sql server database

I need to add one or more specif columns in the Traces table instead of adding value in Payload column

Maye the only way is to create a custom SINK, but I didn't find how to do that

Anyone has already encountered on this requirement?

Answer (score 0):

Follow this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn775003(v=pandp.20).aspx) for implementing custom event sink